# How can I extract the link from a specific class?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<td class="views-field views-field-title">
  <a href="xxxxxxx" class="cat-job-rate recruiter-colorbox-processed">
    xxxxxx
  </a><br>
  <span class="job-label">Organization:</span>
  xxxxx | <span class="job-label">xxxxxx:</span>
  xxxx | <span class="job-label">xxxx:</span> xxxxx
</td>
```

I want to extract a link from a webpage using cheerio from the `class="views-field views-field-title"`. There are so many `a` links on the webpage but I want to extract from the mentioned class only.

Comment: <td class="views-field views-field-title">
            <a href="xxxxxxx" class="cat-job-rate recruiter-colorbox-processed">xxxxxx</a><br><span class="job-label">Organization:</span> xxxxx |   <span class="job-label">xxxxxx:</span>xxxx |    <span class="job-label">xxxx:</span> xxxxx           </td>

Comment: am trying to edit but its deleting characters. i dont know why. so my code is not coming out the way it should however can you use the code in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

As per HTML snippet you shared, below snippet will able to retrieve all the hyperlinks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function getHyperlinks() {
        var parent = document.querySelectorAll(".views-field.views-field-title > a");
        for(let i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
            console.log(parent[i].getAttribute("href"))
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>My First JavaScript</h2>
    <table>
        <td class="views-field views-field-title"> <a href="xxxxxxx" class="cat-job-rate recruiter-colorbox-processed">xxxxxx</a>
            <br><span class="job-label">Organization:</span> xxxxx | <span class="job-label">xxxxxx:</span>xxxx | <span class="job-label">xxxx:</span> xxxxx </td>
    </table>
    <input type="button" onclick="getHyperlinks();" value="click" /> </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi. @arjunan. Am using fetchurl. i also have an option another option i saw from some other example. but still not working can you help me correct the code below?    var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
   var jobList = resp.match(/<div class="show-view-more">\n<a class="btn btn-primary" href=".+?">.*?<\/a>\n<\/div>/gms);

Comment: also , how can i  extract the urls using cheerio?